# PHP preg_replace alternative

Tags: php, preg-replace, deprecated

We're currently getting a preg_replace error message on our site due to deprecation.

Our code is as follows:

```
$out = preg_replace('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!se', "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'", $data);
```

Any suggestions on how this can be replaced with non-deprecated code?

Answer (score 5):

`preg_` is not deprecated. It is just `/e` (as of PHP 5.5):

> The /e modifier is deprecated. Use [preg_replace_callback()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) instead.
>   See the [PREG_REPLACE_EVAL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php#reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.eval) documentation for additional information
>   about security risks.

and as `preg_replace_callback()` is almost identical to `preg_replace()` with exception that it uses callback instead of replacement, update of your code should be quick homework.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the modifiers `s` and `e`. Copied directly from [Deprecated feature sin PHP 5.5.x](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php):

> The [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace) `/e` modifier is now deprecated. Instead, use the [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) function.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I found this "callback_function" that works fine:

```
$fixed_text = preg_replace_callback ( '!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!',
function($m) {
       return ($m[1] == strlen($m[2])) ? $m[0] : 's:' . strlen($m[2]) . ':"' . $m[2] . '";';
},
$text);
```