# Preg replace deprecated, attempting to fix

Tags: javascript, php, html, regex, deprecation-warning

I've just upgraded to PHP 7 and have been hammering out errors associated with deprecated functions, with much success.

Sadly, I've been having trouble fixing the new preg replace methodology for my "view php array in a interactive collapsable javascript thing" code.

The following code:

```
function print_r_tree($data)
{

// capture the output of $this->print_r_tree
   $out = print_r($data, true);

 // replace something like '[element] => <newline> (' with <a href="javascript:toggleDisplay('...');">...</a><div id="..." style="display: none;">
    $out = preg_replace('/([ \t]*)(\[[^\]]+\][ \t]*\=\>[ \t]*[a-z0-9 \t_]+)\n[ \t]*\(/iUe',"'\\1<a href=\"javascript:toggleDisplay(\''.(\$id = substr(md5(rand().'\\0'), 0, 7)).'\');\">\\2</a><div id=\"'.\$id.'\" style=\"display: none;\">'", $out);

  // replace ')' on its own on a new line (surrounded by whitespace is ok) with '</div>
     $out = preg_replace('/^\s*\)\s*$/m', '</div>', $out);

  // print the javascript function toggleDisplay() and then the transformed output
     echo '<script language="Javascript">function toggleDisplay(id) { document.getElementById(id).style.display = (document.getElementById(id).style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block"; }</script>'."\n$out";

  }
```

Generates this warning. 
Warning:  preg_replace(): The /e modifier is no longer supported, use preg_replace_callback instead

Removing the "e" in the first "preg_replace", breaks the javascript thing. I've tried a few preg_replace_callback things as well.

I've been trying to use this link [Replace preg_replace() e modifier with preg_replace_callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454220/replace-preg-replace-e-modifier-with-preg-replace-callback) to help me understand what's broken, but I think my issue is complicated by the javascript.

I'm hoping someone might be able to walk me through this, with respect to my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might find some help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21000320/php-preg-replace-alternative

Comment: Hi, was wondering if you've managed to solve the deprecation warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  `e` modifier is in your first `$out` variable. To transform that, you need to use correctly `preg_replace_callback()`:

```
$out = preg_replace_callback('/([ \t]*)(\[[^\]]+\][ \t]*\=\>[ \t]*[a-z0-9 \t_]+)\n[ \t]*\(/iU', "callbackFunction", $out);

function callbackFunction($matches) {
     return "'".$matches[1]."<a href=\"javascript:toggleDisplay(\''.(\$id = substr(md5(rand().'".$matches[0]."'), 0, 7)).'\');\">".$matches[2]."</a><div id=\"'.\$id.'\" style=\"display: none;\">'";
}
```

See that in preg_replace_callback we define second parameter with `callbackFunction`, that string is parsed to call that function and it passes an array with the matches. So the replacements were in `callbackFunction()` function and the matches are `matches[X]`.

More info:

http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is the combination of the [original](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php#90759) with [Christian's fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54874609/2133918).

```
function print_r_tree($data)
{
    // capture the output of print_r
    $out = print_r($data, true);

    // replace something like '[element] => <newline> (' with <a href="javascript:toggleDisplay('...');">...</a><div id="..." style="display: none;">
    $out = preg_replace_callback('/([ \t]*)(\[[^\]]+\][ \t]*\=\>[ \t]*[a-z0-9 \t_]+)\n[ \t]*\(/iU', 'print_r_tree_callback', $out);

    // replace ')' on its own on a new line (surrounded by whitespace is ok) with '</div>
    $out = preg_replace('/^\s*\)\s*$/m', '</div>', $out);

    // print the javascript function toggleDisplay() and then the transformed output
    return '<script language="Javascript">function toggleDisplay(id) { document.getElementById(id).style.display = (document.getElementById(id).style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block"; }</script>'."\n$out";
}

function print_r_tree_callback($matches) {
    $id = substr(md5(rand().$matches[0]), 0, 7);
    return "$matches[1]<a href=\"javascript:toggleDisplay('$id');\">$matches[2]</a><div id='$id' style=\"display: none;\">";
}
```